# SQLServer: How to pair up ordered data for sequences of arbitrary (and unequal length)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

Here's my scenario: I have two tables A, B which (for the sake of this question are identical):

Table X (PK)

```
ID 
1
2
```

Table A:

```
ID FKID Value Sort
1  1    a     1
2  1    aa    2
3  1    aaa   3
4  2    aaaa  1
5  2    aaaaa 2
```

Table B:

```
ID FKID Value Sort
1  1    b     1
2  1    bb    2
3  2    bbb   1
4  2    bbbb  2
5  2    bbbbb 3
```

Desired Output:

```
FKID ValueA ValueB Sort
1    a      b      1
1    aa     bb     2
1    aaa    (null) 3
2    aaaa   bbb    1
2    aaaaa  bbbb   2
2    (null) bbbbb  3
```

So record *1* has 3-As and 2-Bs and record *2* has 2-As and 3-Bs all nicely paired up by the Sort integer column.

My current solution involves cross joining with a Numbers table. It works but since the number of items in these tables is unbounded my numbers table is largish (the application is theorhetically unbounded but practically, I can limit it to 1000).

I could also generate the numbers table with a function and a subquery but that feels even worse for performance (I know, I need to test it!).

So I was thinking: perhaps there's a better way to approach this problem? I'm hoping for a happy medium between where I am now and merging the tables together.

One more thing: **I'm stuck on SQL Server 2000** :P.

**Update:** Added PK table above to clarify what I was looking for. I also fixed the desired output. Sorry about that.

**Update:** Complete solution:

```
DECLARE @X AS TABLE (ID INT)
DECLARE @A AS TABLE (ID INT, FKID INT, Value VARCHAR(10), Sort INT)
DECLARE @B AS TABLE (ID INT, FKID INT, Value VARCHAR(10), Sort INT)

INSERT INTO @X (ID) VALUES (1)
INSERT INTO @X (ID) VALUES (2)

INSERT INTO @A (ID, FKID, Value, Sort) VALUES (1, 1, 'a',     1)
INSERT INTO @A (ID, FKID, Value, Sort) VALUES (2, 1, 'aa',    2)
INSERT INTO @A (ID, FKID, Value, Sort) VALUES (3, 1, 'aaa',   3)
INSERT INTO @A (ID, FKID, Value, Sort) VALUES (4, 2, 'aaaa',  1)
INSERT INTO @A (ID, FKID, Value, Sort) VALUES (5, 2, 'aaaaa', 2)

INSERT INTO @B (ID, FKID, Value, Sort) VALUES (1, 1, 'b',     1)
INSERT INTO @B (ID, FKID, Value, Sort) VALUES (2, 1, 'bb',    2)
INSERT INTO @B (ID, FKID, Value, Sort) VALUES (3, 2, 'bbb',   1)
INSERT INTO @B (ID, FKID, Value, Sort) VALUES (4, 2, 'bbbb',  2)
INSERT INTO @B (ID, FKID, Value, Sort) VALUES (5, 2, 'bbbbb', 3)

SELECT * FROM @X
SELECT * FROM @A
SELECT * FROM @B

SELECT COALESCE(A.FKID, B.FKID) ID
  ,A.Value
  ,B.Value
  ,COALESCE(A.Sort, B.Sort) Sort
FROM @X X
LEFT JOIN @A A ON A.FKID = X.ID
FULL OUTER JOIN @B B ON B.FKID = A.FKID AND B.Sort = A.Sort
```

Comment: Solved per @Brian's answer. Thanks to everyone for your help. If my vague question led you in a wrong direction, I apologize! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
    coalesce(a.fkid, b.fkid) fkid, 
    A.Value as ValueA, 
    B.Value as ValueB, 
    coalesce(a.sort, b.sort) Sort
from a full outer join b
        on a.fkid = b.fkid
        and a.sort = b.sort
order by fkid, sort
```

Comment: This doesn't produce the results of your desired output, but it matches what you describe in the question. Maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% clear on what you're after, but Try this and see if it is what you want

```
Select Coalesce(a.FKID, b.FKID) FKID,
    a.Value, B.Value, 
    Coalesce(a.Sort, b.Sort) Sort
From TableA a Full Join TableB b
    On a.Sort = b.sort
       And Left(a.value,1) = 'a'
       And Left(b.value,1) = 'b'
       And Len(a.value) = Len(b.value)
```

Comment: The value matches (LEFT/LEN) won't work like that in practice--I just used As and Bs as an example.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.FKID,  A.Value AS ValueA, B.Value AS ValueB, A.Sort
FROM Table1 AS A LEFT JOIN Table2 AS B
ON A.ID = B.ID AND A.FKID = B.FKID
UNION 
SELECT B.FKID,  A.Value AS ValueA, B.Value AS ValueB, B.Sort
FROM Table1 AS A RIGHT JOIN Table2 AS B
ON A.ID = B.ID AND A.FKID = B.FKID
```

Note: This will return duplicate records for a match of ID & FKID (where Sort differs).
If you remove the Sort field from the query, you will get the results, you are looking for.

```
SELECT A.FKID,  A.Value AS ValueA, B.Value AS ValueB, A.Sort AS ASort, 
B.Sort AS BSort
FROM Table1 AS A LEFT JOIN Table2 AS B
ON A.ID = B.ID AND A.FKID = B.FKID
UNION 
SELECT B.FKID,  A.Value AS ValueA, B.Value AS ValueB,
A.Sort AS ASort, B.Sort AS BSort
FROM Table1 AS A RIGHT JOIN Table2 AS B
ON A.ID = B.ID AND A.FKID = B.FKID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select COALESCE(tt1.FKID, tt2.FKID) FKID, 
       tt1.Value ValueA, 
       tt2.Value ValueB,
       CASE WHEN tt1.Sort IS NULL OR tt2.Sort IS NULL
            THEN COALESCE(tt1.Sort, tt2.Sort)
            ELSE CASE WHEN tt1.Sort >= tt2.Sort 
                      THEN tt1.Sort 
                      ELSE tt2.Sort
                 END
       END Sort 
from tt1
full join tt2 on tt1.FKID = tt2.FKID and len(tt1.value) = len(tt2.value)
order by COALESCE(tt1.FKID, tt2.FKID)
```